# Ansible is unable to connect to remote host via ssh

Tags: jenkins, ssh, ansible

I am trying to use jenkins to automate the configuration of my servers. In order to do that, I am using Ansible.

In order to connect to my server, I use the [ssh-agent plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh-agent/).

When running a simple job from jenkins, I can see that the ssh connection works properly:

```
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test ssh
[ssh-agent] Looking for ssh-agent implementation...
[ssh-agent]   Exec ssh-agent (binary ssh-agent on a remote machine)
$ ssh-agent
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-4XDUsG0J48a3/agent.2046
SSH_AGENT_PID=2049
[ssh-agent] Started.
Running ssh-add (command line suppressed)
Identity added: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test ssh@tmp/private_key_1209322285087807037.key (jaep@emmanuels-mbp.lan)
[ssh-agent] Using credentials ubuntu
[test ssh] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins3316727259326040096.sh
+ ssh ubuntu@192.168.50.10 uname -n
dummy-node-01
$ ssh-agent -k
unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
unset SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 2049 killed;
[ssh-agent] Stopped.
Finished: SUCCESS
```

But when I try to use the same method with Ansible, the connection fails:

```
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test ansible
[ssh-agent] Looking for ssh-agent implementation...
[ssh-agent]   Exec ssh-agent (binary ssh-agent on a remote machine)
$ ssh-agent
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-mBo76NlvAkNi/agent.2587
SSH_AGENT_PID=2590
[ssh-agent] Started.
Running ssh-add (command line suppressed)
Identity added: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test ansible@tmp/private_key_1675485652255015509.key (jaep@emmanuels-mbp.lan)
[ssh-agent] Using credentials ubuntu
using credential 8b7b07f7-7e7f-4419-bcc6-2810ff21dec8
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
...
[test ansible] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/shiningpanda4284977286200997881.sh
+ pip3 install -r requirements.txt
...
+ ansible-playbook playbooks/main.yml -i inventory/local
PLAY [dev] *********************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
fatal: [192.168.50.10]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Warning: Permanently added '192.168.50.10' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\nPermission denied (publickey).", "unreachable": true}
ok: [localhost]

TASK [ping the hosts] **********************************************************
ok: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
192.168.50.10              : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   

Build step 'Virtualenv Builder' marked build as failure
$ ssh-agent -k
unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
unset SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 2590 killed;
[ssh-agent] Stopped.
Finished: FAILURE
```

When trying the same process without the ssh-agent, I get the same error message:

```
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test ansible
using credential 8b7b07f7-7e7f-4419-bcc6-2810ff21dec8
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
...
[test ansible] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/shiningpanda3043667756031558264.sh
+ pip3 install -r requirements.txt
...
+ ansible-playbook playbooks/main.yml -i inventory/local

PLAY [dev] *********************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
fatal: [192.168.50.10]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Warning: Permanently added '192.168.50.10' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\nPermission denied (publickey).", "unreachable": true}
ok: [localhost]

TASK [ping the hosts] **********************************************************
ok: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
192.168.50.10              : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   

Build step 'Virtualenv Builder' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

It really looks like the ssh-agent is not taken into account while establishing the ssh connection.

My ansible.cfg looks as follow:

```
[defaults]
roles_path = ./roles
host_key_checking = False
retry_files_enabled = False
inventory = ./inventory/local

[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -o ForwardAgent=yes -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s  -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o IdentitiesOnly=yes
```

I'm really running out of ideas here... Any suggestions?

Comment: If you can run playbook with -vvv options for some extra debug logging, it will provide some more  insight on what is going on.

Comment: Ansible would try to use the keys stored in the .ssh directory inside $HOME.  Do you have the ssh key files for the remote host copied to /var/lib/jenkins?